# How to optimize SQL Server query for multiple updating of records simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql-server, query-optimization, parameterized-query

I have the following code for updating text records from different tables in my SQL Server database i.e.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
           try
            {
                List<string[]> words1 = new List<string[]>();
                string[] stopWords = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\~\Desktop\stopWords_E_Unique_Spaces.txt");

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source="";Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        query.CommandText = "select p_abstract from sub_aminer_paper where aid = 1710594";
                        SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string[] ListElements = new string[2];
                            ListElements[0] = reader["p_abstract"].ToString();
                            ListElements[1] = reader["p_abstract"].ToString();
                            words1.Add(ListElements);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                for (int index = 0; index < words1.Count; index++)
                {
                    foreach (string word in stopWords)
                    {
                        var item = words1.ElementAt(index);
                        item[1] = item[1].ToString().ToLower().Replace(word, " ").Trim();
                        item[1] = Regex.Replace(item[1].ToString(), @"\s+", " ");
                    }
                }
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source="";Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int counter = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < words1.Count; i++)
                        {
                            counter++;
                            var item      = words1.ElementAt(i);
                            var itemKey   = item[0].ToString();
                            var itemValue = item[1].ToString();

                            string query = "select pid from sub_aminer_paper where p_abstract LIKE @p_abstract and aid = 1710594";

                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                            {
                                //string inp = input;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_abstract", itemKey);

                                int id = 0;
                                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                    }
                                    reader.Close();
                                }


                            string update_query = "update sub_aminer_paper set p_abstract_SWR = @p_abstract_SWR where pid = @pid";
                            int res = 0;
                            using (SqlCommand cmd_update = new SqlCommand(update_query, con))
                            {
                                int identity = id;
                                string p_abstractSWR = itemValue;

                                cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", identity);
                                cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_abstract_SWR", p_abstractSWR);

                                res = cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            } Console.WriteLine(counter);
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The **issue** is that I want to update records for multiple `aid`'s i.e. in the query `select p_abstract from sub_aminer_paper where aid = 1710594` whereas this query return multiple records for a single `aid`. Similarly in the update query i.e. `update sub_aminer_paper set p_abstract_SWR = @p_abstract_SWR where pid = @pid` whereas I want to update multiple records for multiple `aid`.
Please help in improving these queries.  Thanks

Comment: this is not a right way to code. you should use store procedure for such cases.

Comment: @AmitSoni can you please give any hint, how to structure required stored procedure ?

Comment: complex logic should be done on SP. i am not aware about your situation. so cant help you up to extend. My opinion, go for SP

Comment: @AmitSoni I want to go for SP and my situation is mentioned above in question, I'll let you clear situation if you are not getting the actual issue, just let me know